# change webforms to mvc in visualstudio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

i created a blank webforms project instead of an MVC 3 project in visual studio, everything runs fine but i dont have my menues

for example when i right click on the Controllers folder i dont get  "Add a controller"  option.

does anyone know without starting a new project how to change the type of project into an MVC one so that i get the correct menus.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you don't have the menu options, it's that it's a completely different type of [web] application and works in different ways. e.g. Webforms has no concept of controllers so even if you did have a menu option it wouldn't get included in the project as you're expecting.

Because webForms and MVC are so different there could never be a 100% reliable conversion utility.

Just create a new project and copy the files already created. I can't imagine you've written that much code before realising that you're in WebForms, not MVC.

If you have got lots of WebForms code you could always just include this in the MVC project until you can convert it (if necessary) at a later time.

**Edit:**
If you just want to change the project type you can edit the csproj file of the webforms project and add the following ProjectTypeGuid `{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};`.
You'll need to update references, files, etc. for this to work but it may be quicker than creating a new project and copying content over. (Especially if you already have the project in source control.)

Note that I've only tested this going from WebForms 4 to MVC2.

Comment: actually a full project was created as it was a clone job, and yeah thanks i know there different totally just checking to see if there is some like config file hack or something that will register it as a MVC project as it is an MVC project, there would also be no problems converting as i have not created webforms code just the actual heading somewere this must be set right? and therefor changeable, then restart VS and bam it is recognised as a MVC project, this is what i am trying to solve, i have now just created a new project but would be handy to know now!  ta

Answer (score 0):

Try updating a MVC to ASP.NET Fall Update Release Candidate. There is a [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAndWebTools20122ReleaseCandidate.aspx) .